# Pre-condition Summary and Description when Exported from Jira are not mapped to Cucumber Background Title and Description section

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, jira-xray

While importing Cucumber feature files to Xray, Background Title and Description are mapped to Pre-condition Summary and Description fields but when exporting a pre-condition issue from Xray it's Summary and Description are not copied over to Cucumber Background Title and Description section. Is this not implemented yet or is this a bug?

[image]

Using Jira DC v8.9.0 and Xray v6.1.3

Comment: 1. Can you please provide more details and a concrete detailed case? 2. Are you using Jira cloud or jira server/datecenter?

Comment: @Sérgio Yeah I should have added more details when I posted. Updated my question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a bug; it follows [these](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Export+Cucumber+Features) rules.
The Background section doesn't have a title; AFAIK the Gherkin specification doesn't support that (see [example](https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/#background) here). The reason for it may be that a Feature can only have a Background, therefore it wouldn't make sense to assign it a name (my guess).
Having the description of the Precondition as a comment on the Background may be feasible to implement; it has to be analyzed by the Xray team. Please contact [Xray support team](https://jira.getxray.app/servicedesk/customer/portal/2/user/login?destination=portal%2F2) and ask for an improvement request, with a concrete example.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, Xray needs pre-condition issue to have Summary and Description from feature Background when importing but when exporting from Xray, Cucumber Background does not them to be mapped. I am okay with the pre-condition issue key in background. Thanks for making it clear.